# UIMA Ruta and UIMA AS

Tags: uima, ruta

Is it possible to use UIMA Ruta with UIMA AS? Unfortunately, I could not find any information on it. Though, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29750049/2817036) on Stackoverflow seems relevant.

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any problems using UIMA Ruta with UIMA AS.

*DISCLAIMER: I ama developer of UIMA Ruta*